# Chrome Extension content script prepend to body not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script for a google chrome browser extension that I am working on, and it injects a horizontal bar to the top of whatever web page that the user is on. The problem is that when I navigate to google.com, googles nav bar appears over my bar. Here is the prepend code

```
$("body").prepend("<iframe class='toolbar' src='http://localhost/toolbar.php' />");
```

Here is how it is supposed to look:

[image: A website that the toolbar works on]

And here is how it looks on google.com
[image: The problem that arises when the content is prepending to google. As you can see the google navbar overlaps with my bar]

I'm trying different approaches, if I fix the problem before anyone else I'll post it. Any help/guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you could do is to wrap the entire page in a `div` with `position: relative; top: 20px; /*or whatever height your bar is*/` then prepend your bar. That would shunt the actual web page down even if some elements are positioned absolute (as they will not be positioned absolutely within the div, rather than the body) and place your bar above the web page. Let me know if this is the answer and I'll post it.

Comment: PS that file doesn't exist on my computer - perhaps, if the above doesn't work, you could post your code?

Comment: Hmm, great idea. I tried it out, but unfortunately there were no results. Here's what i did.

$("body").prepend("<iframe class='toolbar' src='http://localhost/toolbar.php' /><div class='website'>");
$("body").append("</div>");

Comment: Its simpler than that - try `$("body").wrapInner("<div class='website'></div>").prepend("<iframe class='toolbar' src='localhost/toolbar.php'></iframe>");`. That should do the trick.

Comment: You do realize this is what the space below is for right?

Comment: I tend to think of answers as being for code that you know works, and comments more for discussions about code which might work but, for example in this case, we can't really trial it.

Comment: Clarkey. I tried that and there was definitely progress. But now instead of having my toolbar there there is just some empty space. I'm probably missing one key thing.. but I've been coding all day and my brain is mush.

Any thoughts dear sir?

Comment: @FrankieNwafili: I've added the above code as an answer below - please mark it as the answer if it achieves what you want.

Comment: @FrankieNwafili: You may have to set the width / height of the iFrame explicitly - either via CSS or the width / height attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("your html").prependTo('body');
        $("body > :not('#panDiv')").css({position:'relative',top:'23px'});
    },1000);
}); //end $
```

I hope this one is good.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Could you perhaps explain why this works? Thanks again!

Comment: $("body> :not (#pandiv)").css({position:'relative',top:'23'}); means take all body with all frames and controls except #pandiv and put on them stylesheet rule: position:relative; top:23px;

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
//select the body
$("body")
//wrap the content in a div
.wrapInner("<div class='website'></div>")
//prepend the iframe to the body
.prepend("<iframe class='toolbar' src='http://localhost/toolbar.php'></iframe>");
```

Let me know if you can't get this working.

Comment: If I remove the wrapInner portion, the iframe displays but with the original problem of not pushing down the google navbar. If I use this solution with the wrapInner portion, the page is pushed down and there is room for my bar, but it does not show up. I've set the height and width appropriately but to no avail

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure I can help, not without access to all the code or a JSFiddle. Any chance you could supply one?

Comment: @FrankieNwafili: One possibility - it may be there is an error in the JS - can you check in Firebug or Chrome dev tools and see if there are any JS errors coming out of it? You may also like to put an http:// on the beginning of the iframe src - that is probably your problem come to think of it.

Comment: As I suspected, if you try it on the jQuery wrapInner page, the iFrame actually tries to load http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/localhost/toolbar.php which results in a 404. You need http://localhost/toolbar.php instead.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understand what you were getting at with that last comment

Comment: Well the URL of the iFrame is relative, so what you're doing is, if you're on http://www.google.co.uk, you're trying to load http://www.google.co.uk/localhost/toolbar.php. If you change this to http://localhost/toolbar.php, it should work.

Comment: Oh no, I actually already accounted for that by entering it as [http://localhost/toolbar.php](http://localhost/toolbar.php) this entire time. Unfortunately that isn't why it isn't loading. Gah
And thanks a load for your suggestions by the way

Comment: Aha I just realised it is missing something out when it converts the above to links - it should be `http://localhost/toolbar.php`.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's what i meant to say i did. I'm somewhat of an SO syntax noob so the http:// got chopped off my last comment

Comment: lol both in the same boat - not so much of a syntax noob myself, just really tired after coding all day lol. Check Chrome in the console and network tabs, let me know what errors (if any) you're getting. Note that this doesn't appear to work for some sites - try it on here for example.

Comment: Yeah man coding is always so fun until you get that 10 hour bug and you spiral into stress until you finally squash it.
But I think I'll just let it sit for a few hours then come back to it with a fresh head. I'll definitely tell ya if I get it working.
You're a Saint

Comment: Have to admit it does feel good when you do squash that 10 hour bug - much better than one of those tiny ones which takes 2 mins to solve. Yeah let me know if / when you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the z-index css propery of your bar to a big number:

```
<iframe style="z-index:999999;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here

var v = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.top.toString().substring(0, 2);

            if (parseInt(v, 10) > 0) {

                var pxx = (v + 35).toString();
                document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.position = "relative"
                document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.top = pxx + "px";

            }
            else {

                document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.position = "relative"
                document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.top = "35px";
            }


  var url = chrome.extension.getURL('docz/links.html');
  var fRame =  $(document.createElement('iframe'));
  var wrapDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));

    wrapDiv.attr('id','wDiv');
    wrapDiv.css('width','100%');  
    wrapDiv.css('height','35px' );
    wrapDiv.css('position','fixed' );
    wrapDiv.css('top','0 !important');
    wrapDiv.css('z-index','2147482637');   

  fRame.attr('id','fr1');
  fRame.attr('scrolling','no');
  fRame.attr('src',url);
  fRame.attr('frameborder','0');
  fRame.css('position','absolute');
  fRame.css('top', '0 !important');


  fRame.css('width','100%');
  fRame.css('height','35px');
  fRame.css('border','none'); 
  fRame.css('border-radius','10px 10px 10px 10px');
  fRame.css('background-color','silver'); 
  fRame.appendTo(wrapDiv);
  wrapDiv.prependTo(document.body);


try this... before was more crude approach put this code int  $(function(){});
```